# javascript, issue with number rounding

Tags: javascript, decimal, rounding

I knew javascript could have rounding issue with divisions, but not with multiplication. How do you solve those?

```
var p = $('input[name="productsUS"]').val().replace(",", ".");
var t = $('input[name="productsWorld"]').val().replace(",", ".");

if (p >= 0 && t >= 1) {
    var r = p / t;
    r = Math.round(r * 10000) / 10000;
    var aff = (r * 100) + "%";
```

if `p = 100` and `t = 57674`

`r = 0.0017` (ok) and `aff = 0.16999999999999998%` (arg)

How could I obtain `aff = 0.17`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/elegant-workaround-for-javascript-floating-point-number-problem

Comment: are you still having problems?

Comment: Nop, toFixed() was the solution. I just gave time to people to put up answers and to pick one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var aff = (r * 100).toFixed(2) + "%";
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LTnEU/)

`toFixed` on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

Answer (score 2):

`("0.16999999999999998").tofixed(2)` gives you `0.17`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to `aff` to remain a Number instead of being converted to a String, you can use `toFixed` to work around the precision issues and then "cast" it back to a number using the unary `+` operator like so:

```
var n = 0.16999999999999998;

n = +n.toFixed(10); // 0.17
```

You probably want to use a higher precision than 2 decimal places to avoid rounding issues, I used 10 here.

Answer (score 0):

That's a bug in JavaScript (although it also affects a few other languages, such as Python), due to the way it stores non-whole numbers being a bit buggy (binary!). The only way to work around it is to round it to two decimal places.